# Unable to find package file warning in Intellij and Perl plugin

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, ide, perl-module, intellij-plugin

I've the Intellij ultimate edition with the [Perl](https://www.google.de/search?q=perl+intellij&oq=perl+intellij&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2332j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) installed.

I'm getting the title warning for all my `*.pm` files for keywords like `warning`, `strict`, `constant`, as you can see from my screenshot here:

[image]

Why this happens?

Comment: I cannot see much, frankly. Just a screenshot of some syntax highlighted pragmas. May be a little context (the whole script) and the warnings you get (please, both as text, not screenshots!) might lighten the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue until I ensured that my local perl was properly configured in the IDE preferences.

1. `File` >> `Preferences` ... or `Command` + `,` on the Mac.
2. `Language & Frameworks` >> `Perl5` >> `Project`
3. Choose your perl interpreter from the dropdown. If one doesn't exist, then select the Gear button to the right of the dropdown to set one up. (I'm using [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/))
4. Choose a target version to ensure the most correct language features.